# Unity3D:Field text or type signature not found when i use GetStatic<string> to reach a string inside a Jar android plugin

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, jar

i am trying to add an ***android plugin*** to ***unity*** ...i have built an android project in eclipse and i  have export it as *jar* ..then  i have created  Plugins/Android folders inside Assets folder in unity which i have placed the jar file with the AndroidManifest.
The problem is that whenever i try to reach the class inside the plugin and try to get a static string using *GetStatic*  it gives me this error:

```
Exception: Field text or type signature  not found
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <276f2981b14b4cff9d7381915070a7a8>:0)
UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <276f2981b14b4cff9d7381915070a7a8>:0)
UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at <276f2981b14b4cff9d7381915070a7a8>:0)
```

This is the C# code where i try to reach the "text" variable inside the plugin
[image: This is the C# code where i try to reach the "text" variable inside the plugin]

This is the class inside the android plugin
[image: This is the class inside the android plugin]

This the AndroidManifest i placed inside Assets/Plugins/Android
[image: This the AndroidManifest i placed inside Assets/Plugins/Android]

Answer (score 0):

I was so dump ..

The problem is that i was trying to test the project  in the editor  ..and since that library is a different architecture (ARM or MIPS usually) windows will not understand it so he cant access it .

The projec works fine like expected in android device.